# How do you determine the energy of an isotope?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, atoms, isotopes

How do you determine the energy of an isotope? I there a calculation for it? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: What do you mean by "the energy of an isotope"? Is it the [binding energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy) that you are concerned with? Perhaps you should elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: More like energy an electron releases when going through beta decay. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Electron by itself does not go through beta decay. Electrons are released by beta decay of unstable nuclei. And calculation is simple: you take the mass of an unstable atom and subtract from it total mass of decay products (mass of new atom plus mass of electron(s) released). Multiplying this mass defect by $c^2$ gives energy of the decay reaction.